# ASP.NET MVC display users recent searches and additions to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC site that can be accessed by an Active Directory group. The basic functionality of the site is:

- User can navigate to many different pages which display data from different tables in the SQL Server
- User can search by any column in each table on the site to display corresponding records
- User can create/delete/edit previously stored records from the connected SQL Server tables

I want to create a main page for the site that is personalized for each user in Active Directory. I was hoping to display previous changes to the database (i.e records added or edited) as well as the user's previous search history so that they can click on a link and it takes them to a results table that they have accessed before.

I have looked into logging the user's activity, but so far all I can find information on is logging errors/bugs that different users experience on the site. I want to log the user's searches/database changes.

Does anyone have advice on how I can do this? I was thinking about adding a table for storing this information in the SQL Server database, but I am unsure how this would work for separation by different users. For example, if User A searches for "xyz" and User B searches for "Abc", when User A relaunches the site, the previous search history should only show "xyz"

**EDIT**: another question I thought of, if I were to create a table that follows this basic format:

[image]

Where the User column is a foreign column connecting to the Active Directory user (i.e. 3 -> John Smith and 7 -> Jane Doe), is it possible to connect a foreign key column representing which user made the changes in the site to an Active Directory group? That way if John Smith made a change in the site, when he logs in, any data that corresponds to only him is displayed?

Comment: "I am unsure how this would work for separation by different users"...how about adding a column in the table to store the username of the person who made the search? And maybe the date/time that they made it, if you want the concept of "recent" to be involved as well.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply! I just made an edit in my post because I thought of that same idea. Adding a column in a table that stores which user made which change would make sense, however I am unsure how to connect the active directory user to the table storing site activity. Do you know how to do this? Or I could simply get the users login information and store that in the table, but I am also not sure what code would allow me to get the users id

Comment: Just store their username in a varchar column. You can pass it in from your ASP.NET application, which always knows who the current user is when Windows Authentication is switched on